# UI getting blocked while fetching image path using Photos Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

```
- (void)updateFetchRequest {
    PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];

    switch (self.imagePickerController.mediaType) {
        case QBImagePickerMediaTypeImages:
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %ld", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
            break;

        case QBImagePickerMediaTypeVideos:
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %ld", PHAssetMediaTypeVideo];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    self.fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetCollections[0] options:options];

    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editoptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];
    [editoptions setCanHandleAdjustmentData:^BOOL(PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData) {
        return [adjustmentData.formatIdentifier isEqualToString:AdjustmentFormatIdentifier] && [adjustmentData.formatVersion isEqualToString:@"1.0"];
    }];

    NSLog(@"fectarray %@",self.fetchResult);

    PHImageRequestOptions *option = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
    option.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    option.synchronous = YES;
    option.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
    PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = self.assetCollections[0];

    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;  // New C99 uses __typeof(..)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Work Dispatched");
        PHAsset *asset;

        SyncAlbumNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetCollection.localizedTitle];

        for (int i=0; i<self.fetchResult.count; i++) {
            asset = weakSelf.fetchResult[i];
            NSLog(@"asset is %@",asset);

            [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editoptions
                completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
                NSLog (@"imageUrl %@",imageURL);

                // [weakSelf getLocalId:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageURL]];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getLocalId:)
                    withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageURL]
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
                if(uparray.count == 0){
                    [arrayAssets addObject:asset];
                    [newArray addObject:asset];
                    if(arrayAssets.count !=0){
                        [dict setValue:[NSArray arrayWithArray:arrayAssets]
                            forKey:assetCollection.localizedTitle];
                        NSLog(@"dict count is %lu",(unsigned long)dict.count);
                    }
                    [SyncAlbum getArraySubTypes];
                    NSLog(@"arrayAssets count %d",arrayAssets.count);
                    NSLog(@"fetchresult count %d",weakSelf.fetchResult.count);
                    __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                    if (strongSelf) {
                        if(arrayAssets.count + 2 + alcount == strongSelf.fetchResult.count){
                            [strongSelf SyncAlbums];
                        }
                        // When finished call back on the main thread:
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            // Return data and update on the main thread
                            // Task 3: Deliver the data to a 3rd party component (always do this on the main thread, especially UI).
                        });
                    }
                    //add count to array asset
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"asset already uploaded");
                    alcount++;
                    //asset already upload count here..
                }
            }];
        }
    });
}
```

My UI gets blocked when executing this method. I am using SQLite database. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where is updateFetchRequest being called from?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
option.synchronous = YES;
```

If you cmd+click on synchronous shows that

```
// return only a single result, blocking until available (or failure). Defaults to NO
```

Also setting

```
PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode
```

to `HighQualityFormat` will force synchronous = true.

Comment: Hey. I tried making it asynchronous but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for the help.  The method [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editoptions
                completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL; }]; was blocking the UI. I changed the method and it worked. Thanks .